# html5 - how to collapsing and expanding for complicated table elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image]

Hi, I need a expanding and collapsing function for a table. The code found on line most are for  and then in js define a function for this tr class.

But my case is more complicated as seen as picture. It will expand after clicking "Parameter 1" and show a merged cell and 2 cells.

So in this case, how can I realize this function? Thanks in advance.

Attached is a simple snippet for the table for your test:

https://jsfiddle.net/knspgwkq/

**html for test table**

```
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5">Summary 1</td>
    <td colspan="2"><div align="center">1 st level</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div class="P1">Parameter 1</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Sub level-1 </td>
    <td>Sub parameter (1)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sub parameter (2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div class="P2">Parameter 2</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('.P1').click(function(){
  $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
  $(this).nextUntil('.P2').slideToggle(100, function(){
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi@jcubic, may I know where you have edited?

Comment: he added tag "jquery"

Comment: When you have enough reputation you can edit just tags.

Comment: This will work when you add P1 P2 classes to tr elements

Comment: @jcubic, there is a problem because "Parameter" is a <td>, instead of <tr>:<td colspan="2"><div class="P1">Parameter 1</div></td>.

Comment: Collapsing/expanding table rows animation usually doesn't work as expected anyway due to `display: table/table-cell;`. Here fixed jsFiddle but of course animation doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/knspgwkq/4/  Here example to let animation runs but that's no more a table: https://jsfiddle.net/knspgwkq/5/

Comment: @A. Wolff, thank you for the "+" example, I will try both of your and Paran0a's suggestion.

Comment: @A. Wolff, I tried your animation method to a more complex case shown in  https://jsfiddle.net/gka7312L/ explained in the post of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649461/html-javascript-expanding-function-changes-the-level-relationship-incorrectly. But when collapsing, the level relationship will be changed. Could you please help take a look if interested, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adding your custom data attribute to the cells that you wish to control?
Live example https://jsfiddle.net/knspgwkq/7/

Your parent will hold `data-collapsable-parent` with some key value.
And your children that you wish to hide/show with above parent will hold `data-collapsable-child` with the same key value as parent.

And if you need additional collapsing expanding elements check this example
By clicking Parameter 1 then Sub parameter (2) you will open additional element.

https://jsfiddle.net/knspgwkq/9/

```js
$('[data-collapsable-parent]').click(function(){
  var child = $(this).attr("data-collapsable-parent");
  $('[data-collapsable-child="'+ child + '"]').toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
 [data-collapsable-child] {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5">Summary 1</td>
    <td colspan="2"><div align="center">1 st level</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" data-collapsable-parent="1"><div class="P1">Parameter 1</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-collapsable-child="1" rowspan="2">Sub level-1 </td>
    <td data-collapsable-child="1" >Sub parameter (1)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-collapsable-child="1" >Sub parameter (2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div class="P2">Parameter 2</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But there is no animation at all

Comment: I added some kind of animation:/ Don't know it that fits the needs.

Comment: Ya but your animation really looks broken imho. That's said, you cannot really animate any table row

Comment: Where does OP mention animation? He only mentions `show a merged cell and 2 cells`

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't understand the question clearly, I didn't know animation is required. Should I remove my answer?

Comment: Hi@Paran0a, thanks for this idea, I have a doubt for [data-collapsable-child="1"]. If I need to further expand when clicking "Sub parameter (1)", do I need to change "1" to "2"?

Comment: @Paran0a No, don't remove it. Maybe that's fitting OP needs. OP didn't clearly said she wants any animation **only** her code suggests it

Comment: @Héléna I made a mistake in the code by hardcoding [data-collapsable-child="1"]. You can place [data-collapsable-child] there instead.

If you need additional sub parameters check these examples. https://jsfiddle.net/knspgwkq/8/

If you click Sub parameter (2) it should open additional td.

Comment: @Paran0a, regarding jsfiddle.net/knspgwkq/8, after expanding "Sub parameter (3)", then you click again the "Parameter 1", the "Sub parameter (3)" cannot be collapsed. Do you have any solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea: use two toggles to get the upward collapse effect, and the downward expand effect (without modifying your table structure).

```js
// Basic toggle without animation
//$('.P1').on("click", function() {
//  $(this).closest("tr").nextUntil('.P2').toggle();
//});

// Better sliding toggle
$('.P1').on("click", function() {
  $trs = $(this).closest("tr").nextUntil('.P2');
  $trs.eq(1).find("td").eq(0).slideToggle(100, function() {
    $trs.eq(0).slideToggle(100);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5">Summary 1</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div align="center">1 st level</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="P1">Parameter 1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Sub level-1</td>
    <td>Sub parameter (1)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sub parameter (2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="P2">Parameter 2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your idea, as I have accepted Paran0a's answer, sorry I cannot accept 2 at the same time. But it is good to know this method as well