# HTML javascript: expanding function changes the level relationship incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

The problem is explained in the picture below. Once clicking the expanding function of "Parameter 1", the level of "Parameter 2" will change as seen in the middle picture. But actually it should remain in the same level.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**JAVASript**

```
$('.P1').click(function() {
  $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value) {
    return value == '-' ? '+' : '-'
  });
  $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:has(.P2)').slideToggle(100, function() {});
});

$('.Sub-parameter-1').click(function() {
  $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value) {
    return value == '-' ? '+' : '-'
  });
  $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:has(.Sub-parameter-2)').slideToggle(100, function() {});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="6">Summary </td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div align="center">1 st level</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="P1"><span>-</span>Parameter 1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">L1</td>
    <td colspan="2"><div class="Sub-parameter-1"><span>-</span>Sub parameter (1)</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>L2</td>
    <td>description</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div class="Sub-parameter-2"><span>-</span>Sub parameter (2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="P2">Parameter 2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/gft08cmb/4/

**EDIT based on answer**

When applying the answer to more than 1 row of sub parameter, then the "Parameter 2" still changes its level seen in following link.

https://jsfiddle.net/gka7312L/  or https://jsfiddle.net/p2a2wxfv/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `rowspan attribute in L1` is making problems since it should change from 3 to 2 and back in your case.

This works as you would want I think: https://jsfiddle.net/gft08cmb/6/

You should of course make it dynamic if your data is going to be dynamic also.
So probably a count of rows etc. and then manipulate based on this.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: thanks a lot~let me try the same method to others first.

Comment: I tried your method to a more complex case show in https://jsfiddle.net/p2a2wxfv/ or https://jsfiddle.net/gka7312L/, then when collapsing sub-parameter(1), "Parameter 2" will still change its level. Could you please help take a look, thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to be working fine? Parameter 2 does not change its level for me?

Comment: ，sorry the above link is outdated, please try this one: https://jsfiddle.net/p2a2wxfv/1/ or https://jsfiddle.net/gka7312L/1/. Thanks.

Comment: As I mentioned in this answer - you should make this dynamic based on your data: for this new situation, your L1 will have to go from 4 to 2 and back, so you would have to do something like: https://jsfiddle.net/p2a2wxfv/2/ (but don't do this exactly! This is hardcoded solution which of course won't work for various data and levels).

Comment: ok now I see, is there a way to hide total "L1" part by default like shown in the most left picture? I used to try "$('.P1 + tr').hide();" but not hit the point. If you think it is a different question, I could open another post for this question, thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use jquery for that, depends on what you want to accomplish again. You want to hide it permanently or on opening/closing? https://jsfiddle.net/7tvgnw22/ A new question if probably the best here ..